# How can I fix my silver sharpie?

Tags: drawing, paper, markers

So recently I pulled my mint condition -or so i thought- silver sharpie out from my art box. I never dipped it in anything or something, but for some reason, the nib has turned brown and only a small spot actually writes okay. I only ever used it a few times and now it is not metallic, but instead watery and grey. not to mention it leaves brown liquid on my paper.. anyone know what to do?

Comment: Sharpies don't last forever. :(

Comment: My solution would be buy a new sharpie, its only $2 for a two pack.